# Capture "Enter" keypress with numeric input in Android/Cordova/Knockout

Tags: android, cordova, knockout.js

I am creating an Android application using Cordova/PhoneGap 2.5.0, Knockout 2.1.0 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.0.

I have created an input with type "number", this input is databound with Knockout on it's value. It is also databound to a key press event. I'm intending to catch the user pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: $root.myInputValue, event: { keypress: $root.myInputKeypress }" min="0" step="1" max="29">


self.myInputKeypress = function() {
    var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);

    alert(keyCode);

    if (keyCode === 13) {
        //Do work here

        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

When I press an allowed key such as a number the code runs as expected and the pressed keys code is alerted. When I press <kbd>enter</kbd> on the keyboard nothing happens, it seems that Android is suppressing events from keys it thinks are not relevant.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so that I can capture the user hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>?

Comment: Please check what key code it returns for the backspace key.

Comment: Hi, no key code is returned for backspace either (the same applies to keys such as +, *, -). Android seems to be suppressing key presses for keys it thinks don't apply to a numeric input.

Comment: I've observed similar behaviour in other places as well. According to the text I've read, Android is suppressing key presses for non-visible characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comments SHANK. It looks like I have a choice between capturing "enter" events or having my inputs as type "number". It would be nice to find this documented somewhere to make sure but I've not been able to.

Comment: I suggest trying either of event: {'afterkeydown':$root.myInputKeypress } or event: {'input':$root.myInputKeypress }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Ionic/Angular**

```
<input ng-keypressed="myKeyPressed($event)" ng-model="myField">

self.myKeyPressed = function(keyEvent) {
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == 13) //do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this could work in your situation using jquery mobile

```
$('.ui-input-text').live('keyup', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // 'Go' pressed do something
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi Put your text box in form tag

```
 <form id="Articleform" name="Article">
                          <input type="number" data-bind="value: $root.myInputValue, event: { keypress: $root.myInputKeypress }" min="0" step="1" max="29">
                        </form>
```

and add event form submit tage

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Articleform").on('submit', function (event) {
        alert("enter");
        return false;
    });
```

when you click on go alert is open

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was with number field the keycode for enter is 9 on my device, on simulator it is 13.

This works for me:

```
$('.ui-input-text').live('keyup', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    // 'Go' pressed do something
}});
```