# Enter key not detected by Android 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, android-softkeyboard, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to catch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press event for Android 2.3 (presumably 2.x)

This is the code I'm using to test the problem:

```
<input type="number" />

<script>
    $(document).keydown(function(e) { // also tried keyup, keypress
        alert(e.which);
    });
</script>
```

I get a relevant value for any keys, but it does not work with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (expected value of 13).

It seems that Android does not listen to the not allowed characters ([Capture "Enter" keypress with numeric input in Android/Cordova/Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784850/capture-enter-keypress-with-numeric-input-in-android-cordova-knockout))
Is there any solution or workaround ?